# React Downshift JS select all onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, downshift

I'd like to get this functionality in a downshift search box component

`<input onfocus="this.select();" onmouseup="return false;" />`

so that when a user clicks on the search box it will select all the text

I've tried adding it directly to the input element but it doesn't work. Downshift has a state reducer and I tried adding it there but it doesn't work either or I'm not doing it right

I'm guessing it is possible with the stateReducer but I don't know how to do it

https://github.com/paypal/downshift#statereducer

Comment: What does onFocus={() => this.select()} do.

Comment: Please show what code you have.

Comment: here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/kentcdodds/downshift-examples/tree/master/?module=%2Fsrc%2Fordered-examples%2F01-basic-autocomplete.js&moduleview=1

Comment: You should post the code here so other people can see it :)

Comment: Kinda hard to read your code, but you can add a `ref` to the `input` and then use `ref.select()` on it and it should work.